# Change base line position on stratigraphic plots

Tags: r, plot, lattice

How can I manually adjust the x-axis baseline position for a specific panel in a stratigraphic plot?

For example, here's Stratiplot from analogue:

```
library(analogue)
data(V12.122)
Depths <- as.numeric(rownames(V12.122))

(plt <- Stratiplot(Depths ~ O.univ + G.ruber + G.tenel + G.pacR,
                   data = V12.122,  type = c("h","l","g","smooth")))
```

[image]

How can I set the baseline for the panel for G. ruber so that it's set at 0.4, rather than 0, as we see in the plot above?

This means that the bars originate at 0.4, with values >0.4 going to the right of the baseline, and values <0.4 going to the left of the baseline.

Possibly related: [Change x-axis limits on stratigraphic plots (ie. multi-panel plots)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34645201/1036500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a dirty hack but, in the spirit of the Q&A you linked, here's a way to achieve that:

```
# Create a dummy variable with the offset (you can also rewrite the column instead)
V12.122$G.ruber.mod <- V12.122$G.ruber-0.4
# Plot as normal
(plt <- Stratiplot(Depths ~ O.univ + G.ruber.mod + G.tenel + G.pacR,
                   data = V12.122,  type = c("h","l","g","smooth")))
# Modify the range so that it takes negative values
plt$x.limits[[2]] <- range(V12.122$G.ruber.mod, na.rm = TRUE)
# Modify where the labels are drawn for that plot:
plt$x.scales$at <- list(O.univ=FALSE,
                        G.ruber.mod=seq(-.1,.1,by=.05),
                        G.tenel=FALSE,
                        G.pacR=FALSE)
# Modify what the labels says for that plot:
plt$x.scales$labels <- list(O.univ=FALSE,
                        G.ruber.mod=seq(-.1,.1,by=.05) + 0.4,
                        G.tenel=FALSE,
                        G.pacR=FALSE)
# Replot:
latticeExtra::resizePanels(plt, w=c(5,5,5,5))
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks very much, that is spot on, exactly what I needed.